# How do I get specific items from firestore in a gridview in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, gridview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with `Firebase Firestore` in a `Gridview` in `Flutter`. I'm trying to only get the items where the `uid` from the user matches with the records in `Firestore`. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Or I get the result I want, but the records I don't want to have, are empty space in the `Gridview`. This empty space are other records, that don't match with the `uid`. Or the loop stops the first time the `uid`'s don't match.

[image: The code I have at the moment, giving the desired result, but with empty space]

If I return `null` in the else statement, the loop stops once there is one false match.
Is there a way possible how I can only get the records I want in the `Gridview`, without the empty space before it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

Change your stream to this

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore
    .instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('uid', isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser())
    .snapshots(),
```

And then your other if statement comparing the uid won't be necessary anymore

**Why that works**

The [where()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) function pre-filters the collection, so you only fetch the documents that meet the condition, which in this case, is when the uid matches. Your only error was that you were comparing the uid after every document had already been retrieved.